# Trouble using BX Slider in Sharepoint 2013 - returns list items as undefined

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, bxslider

I'm trying to deploy the bxslider Jquery image slider library on an installation of Sharepoint 2013, and I need help troubleshooting my JQuery code.

What I'm Trying to Do: Access a list of user-submitted news articles which may or may not have images attached, and run those articles with approval status "approved" one at a time on bxslider.

What is Happening: bxslider is finding the list, and it's finding the articles, but most of the information I'm trying to read comes back "undefined". Currently all I'm getting is the article title.

I also need to get the article's publication date (stored in a list column called "Date"), the author's name (in column "articleAuthor") and the actual text of the article (in column "Article Text" -- the space is included in the column name.)

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
try {
$().SPServices({ 
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,

    //Setup Caml query for all approved news articles, allow for the possiblity of attachments

    CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><IncludeAttachmentUrls>True</IncludeAttachmentUrls></QueryOptions>", 
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='_ModerationStatus' /><Value Type='ModStat'>Approved</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",

    listName: "project1News",

    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      //alert(Status);
      var count = 0;

    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
        count++;
        var image= $(this).attr("ows_Attachments") != '0' ? $(this).attr("ows_Attachments") : '';
        var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
        var date = $(this).attr("ows_Date");
        var author = $(this).attr("ows_articleAuthor");
        var article = $(this).attr("ows_Article Text");

        //Setup article list item

        $('.bxslider').prepend('<li><div class="newsWrapper">'+
            '<table cellpadding="10"><tr><td width="400" valign="top">'+
            '<a href="' + image + '" data-lightbox="image-' + count + '"><img src="' + image + '" alt="NewsImage"/></a>'+
            '</td><td width="640" valign="top" cell-padding="10"><h3 class="newsTitle">'+  title +'</h3>'+
            '<h3 class="newsAuthor">Posted ' + date + ' by ' + author + '</h3>'+
            '<h3 class="newsBody">'+ article + '</h3></td></tr></table></div></li>');
      });
    }
  });
  }

  catch (err) {
        alert("Something failed: " + err.message);
  }
});
```

The Jquery command to actually execute the slider is stored in the code file for the webpart that actually contains the slider.

Finally, for the record, I am referencing the following JQuery libraries in my webpart code:

1. jquery 1.8.2 (also tried 1.10.2 -- no change)
2. bxslider.min.js -- the BX Slider Jquery Library
3. jquery.SPServices-2014.01.min.js -- A JQuery library "designed to make JQuery on Sharepoint much easier." Ha, I say.
4. SP.js, through a server token.

This is JQuery above my level, and I need all the help I can get. I'm just starting learning Sharepoint, so I've probably got a lot of greenhorn mistakes in this code. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing an option in the rest call to get the specific fields. I believe title and ID come through automatically which would explain why the rest are undefined.

`CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='ColumnA' /><FieldRef Name='ColumnB' /></ViewFields>"`